# IPFS add files ISSUE

Tags: ipfs

I'm currently having issue with writing an script for uploading a file to IPFS. For some reason I'm always getting a TypeError, in which ipfs.files.add or ipfs.add is not a function. How could I resolve this?

My Code:

[image]

Comment: Add code direclty instead of posting image.

Comment: Hi Narendra here is my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62649387/ipfs-add-is-not-working-for-ipfs-client-v44-3-0-how-can-i-resolve-this